# What Best Practice to Submit a Failed Request Again

Tags: android, jwt, asynchttpclient, android-async-http, loopj

My `AsyncHttpClient` class is as follows.

*ApiHttpClient.java*

```
package virtualsystems.com.br.financial.client;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;

import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.HttpRequestInterceptor;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.HttpResponseInterceptor;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class ApiHttpClient {
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://MY_IP_LOCAL_NETWORK/";
    private static final Integer RETRY_COUNT = 2;
    private static final Integer RETRY_DELAY = 500;
    private static final Boolean URL_ENCODING = true;

    private static AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

    public ApiHttpClient() {
        client.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        client.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        client.setUserAgent("Apache-HttpClient-AsyncHttpClient (Linux; Android 6.0) UNAVAILABLE (Java/0) Mobile");
        client.setURLEncodingEnabled(URL_ENCODING);
        client.setMaxRetriesAndTimeout(RETRY_COUNT, RETRY_DELAY);
    }

    private static String getAbsoluteUrl(String relativeUrl) {
        return BASE_URL + relativeUrl;
    }

    public static void get(Context context, String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
        client.get(context, getAbsoluteUrl(url), params, responseHandler);
    }

    public static void post(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
        client.post(getAbsoluteUrl(url), params, responseHandler);
    }

    public static void delete(Context context, String url, Header[] headers, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
        client.delete(context, getAbsoluteUrl(url), headers, params, responseHandler);
    }

    public static void put(Context context, String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
        client.put(context, getAbsoluteUrl(url), params, responseHandler);
    }

    public static void addResponseInterceptor(HttpResponseInterceptor interceptor) {
        Log.d("ApiHttpClient", client.getHttpClient().getClass().getName());
        Log.d("ApiHttpClient", "is DefaultHttpClient: " + (client.getHttpClient() instanceof DefaultHttpClient));
        DefaultHttpClient defaultHttpClient = (DefaultHttpClient) client.getHttpClient();
        defaultHttpClient.addResponseInterceptor(interceptor);
    }

    public static void addRequestInterceptor(HttpRequestInterceptor interceptor) {
        Log.d("ApiHttpClient", client.getHttpClient().getClass().getName());
        Log.d("ApiHttpClient", "is DefaultHttpClient: " + (client.getHttpClient() instanceof DefaultHttpClient));
        DefaultHttpClient defaultHttpClient = (DefaultHttpClient) client.getHttpClient();
        defaultHttpClient.addRequestInterceptor(interceptor);
    }
}
```

In my Activity

*MainActivity.java*

```
package virtualsystems.com.br.financial;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;

import java.io.IOException;

import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.HttpException;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.HttpRequest;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.HttpRequestInterceptor;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.client.HttpClient;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.protocol.HttpContext;
import virtualsystems.com.br.financial.client.ApiHttpClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    ApiHttpClient apiHttpClient = new ApiHttpClient();
    UserSession userSession = UserSession.getInstance(MainActivity.this);

    @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);UserSession userSession = UserSession.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle( this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        TextView navUsername = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.nav_header_username);
        TextView navEmail = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.nav_header_email);
        ImageView navAvatar = (ImageView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.nav_header_avatar);

        navUsername.setText(userSession.getUserName());
        navEmail.setText(userSession.getUserEmail());

        String imgURL = (String) userSession.getUserAvatar();

        RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
        requestOptions.placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);
        requestOptions.error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);

        Glide.with(this)
                .load(imgURL)
                .apply(requestOptions)
                .into(navAvatar);

        displayFragment(R.id.nav_home);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Settings Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        displayFragment(id);

        return true;
    }

    private void displayFragment(int itemId){
        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (itemId){
            case R.id.nav_categories:
                fragment = new Categories();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_home:
                fragment = new BillsTotal();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_bills:
                fragment = new Bills();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_logout:
                logoutUser();
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null){
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
            ft.commit();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }

    private void logoutUser() {
        apiHttpClient.addRequestInterceptor(new HttpRequestInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public void process(HttpRequest request, HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException {
                request.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + userSession.getUserToken());
            }
        });

        apiHttpClient.post("api/logout", null, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler(){
            String responseMessage = "";

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                responseMessage = "Disconected";
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                switch (statusCode){
                    case 400:
                        responseMessage = "Bad Request - Invalid Token";
                        break;
                    case 401:
                        responseMessage = "Unauthorized - Invalid Token";
                        break;
                    case 500:
                        responseMessage = "Could not Invalidate Token";
                        break;
                    default:
                        String errorCode = ((Integer) statusCode).toString();
                        String errorMsg = responseBody.toString();
                        responseMessage = "Error: " + errorCode + "\n" + errorMsg;
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                super.onFinish();
                userSession.clearSession();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), responseMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When the token expires, the API returns a **JSONObject** containing `{"error": "token_expired"}` and error **401**.

In the *logoutUser()* method, I handle errors with switch. In case the request fails (**onFailure**) because the token is expired, and error **401** is returned, what is the best way to send a **POST** request to update the token and then resend the logout request, for example.

Comment: How do you handle expired tokens in other methods besides logoutUser?

Comment: I'm not dealing with expired tokens at the moment, I'm looking to know the best practice to be able to apply to all methods where the expired token will return me an error.

Comment: What is your authorization method (e.g. OAuth), and what API are you trying to access?

Comment: I am accessing an API, which returns me a token, when I pass through authentication (username and password). Backend in Laravel PHP and Tokens JWT.

Comment: I am the library "com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient" for AsyncHttpClient in the client application on android.